How do I make the "find" string in vscode's find and replace box easier to see?
If I highlight a string and press Ctrl + F, it gets highlighted in the find/replace window that drops down.
However, in my current color scheme, it's impossible to see the contents of this string. The text and background color seem to be the same color.
How do I change this?
Here's what it looks like when partially highlighted. The highlighted part is very difficult to see.


You want to modify this theme color:
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    // "input.background":"#fe0c0c",    // you could also change the find widget's input background

    "selection.background": "#ff0000",   // change this

selection.background is described as this:

The background color of text selections in the workbench (e.g. for
input fields or text areas). Note that this does not apply to
selections within the editor.

